# Konva JS - Tooltip with image

Tags: konvajs

Is it possible to add an image to `Konva.tooltip()`?

I'm currently trying to make a tooltip that looks like a media object [like this](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code), but the documentation only shows normal text label and I don't have any idea about how to do it except with :

1. Create a big-sized tooltip
2. Add an image with `Konva.Image()`
3. Add the descriptive text beside the image.

But, I have to create many tooltip and customizing each one of them would be ridiculous.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Konva.Label` doesn't support images inside. Only text and rectangle (`Konva.Tag`).

But you can just create a `Konva.Group` and add everything you need (images, texts, shapes) into it and style it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome. I followed the link and read the article. At its heart, the question you are asking is a very broad one.  Essentially you are coming to the realisation that you 'can' create your tooltips individually, but that the tooltip is a pattern that repeats and so it would be better to have a means to wrap that behaviour in some container that hides all the detail, then just call for the container to create another tootlip, and another, and another.  You can see this approach labelled with various names from DRY, OO, design patterns, encapsulation and components.  I recommend that you do some research on how to construct modern component-based UI's using JavaScript. At a minimum, if you want to DIY then you need to look at creating objects in JavaScript, but you might find along as you go along a JS library that works for you and your current project. Good luck.